How do I delete a systemd transient service like one created by systemd-run?
I have a transient systemd service created indirectly by a timer-based job and can't figure out how to get rid of the failed service entry in systemd's services list once the timer is disabled.
The service and timer are created with something like this (actual command run by timer replaced for simplicity):
$ systemd-run --user \
    --property RefuseManualStart=no \
    --on-calendar=hourly \
    --timer-property=AccuracySec=5m \
    --unit="myservice" "/bin/false"

$ systemctl start --user "myservice.service"

which results in
$ systemctl --user list-units '*myservice*'
  UNIT              LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
● myservice.service loaded failed failed  /bin/false 
  myservice.timer   loaded active waiting /bin/false

as expected. But even once I stop and delete the timer itself with
$ systemctl --user stop myservice.timer

there's still a failed service shown:
$ systemctl --user list-units '*myservice*'
  UNIT              LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● myservice.service loaded failed failed /bin/false

explicitly stopping it does nothing:
$ systemctl --user stop myservice.service  
$ systemctl --user list-units '*myservice*'
  UNIT              LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● myservice.service loaded failed failed /bin/false

Even a systemctl --user daemon-reload doesn't get rid of it. I can't find any options for deleting it, and it doesn't seem to have a unit file.
How do I get rid of it?

You have to use systemctl --user reset-failed myservice.service:
$ systemctl --user reset-failed myservice.service                                           
$ systemctl --user list-units '*myservice*'
  UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION

0 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.

because transient services are only removed when stopped and not failed.
